# Change of basis matrix in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $(X, \mathbb{F}), (Y, \mathbb{F})$ are a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ ,and that $U_1 = \{x_i\}^n_{i = 1}\subset X, V_1 = \{y_j\}^m_{j = 1}\subset Y$ are a vector space basis. If $T : X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear transformation, then for every $x\in X$,

$$\begin{align}[T(x)]^{U_1}_{V_1} = \biggr[T\bigr(\sum_{i = 1}\alpha_i x_i\bigr)\biggr]^{U_1}_{V_1} &=  \biggr[\sum^n_{i = 1}\alpha_i T(x_i)\biggr]^{U_1}_{V_1}\\ &= \biggr[\sum^m_{j = 1}\sum^n_{i = 1}\alpha_{i}\beta_{ij}y_j\biggr]^{U_1}_{V_1}\\ &= \biggr[[T(x_1)]_{V_1}\cdots [T(x_n)]_{V_1}\biggr][x]_{U_1}\\ &= [T]_{V_1}[x]_{U_1}\end{align}\tag{1}$$

Let's further suppose that $V_2 = \{z_k\}^m_{k = 1}\subset Y$ is another basis in $Y$. In which case, for every $1\leq k\leq m$, there exists a collection of scalars $\{\theta_{kj}\}^m_{j = 1}\in \mathbb{F}$ such that $z_k = \sum^{m}_{j = 1}\theta_{kj}y_j$, and so, for every $y\in Y$,

$$\begin{align}[y]_{V_2} = \biggr[\sum^m_{k = 1}c_k z_k\biggr]_{V_2} = \biggr[\sum^m_{j = 1} \sum^m_{k = 1}c_k\theta_{kj}y_j\biggr]_{V_1} &= \begin{pmatrix}\theta_{11}c_{1} & \theta_{12}c_{2}&\cdots & \theta_{1m}c_m\\ \theta_{21}c_1 & \theta_{22}c_2 & \cdots & \theta_{2m}c_m \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ \theta_{m1}c_{1} & \theta_{m2}c_2 &\cdots &\theta_{mm}c_{m}\end{pmatrix}\\ &= \begin{pmatrix}\theta_{11} & \theta_{12}&\cdots & \theta_{1m}\\ \theta_{21} & \theta_{22} & \cdots & \theta_{2m} \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ \theta_{m1} & \theta_{m2} &\cdots &\theta_{mm}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_m\end{pmatrix} \\ &= P^{V_1}_{V_2}[y]_{V_1}\end{align}\tag{2}$$

Where $[P]^{V_1}_{V_2} = \begin{pmatrix}\theta_{11} & \theta_{12}&\cdots & \theta_{1m}\\ \theta_{21} & \theta_{22} & \cdots & \theta_{2n} \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ \theta_{m1} & \theta_{m2} &\cdots &\theta_{mm}\end{pmatrix}$ is said to be change of basis matrix.

If $S^{U_1}_{U_2}\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ denotes the change of matrix that is obtained in $(X, \mathbb{F})$, i.e $[x]_{U_2} = S^{U_1}_{U_2}[x]_{U_1}$, then $T : X\rightarrow Y$ transforms as

$$[T(x)]^{U_2}_{V_2} = P^{V_1}_{V_2}[T(x)]^{U_2}_{V_1} = P^{V_1}_{V_2}[T]_{V_1}[x]_{U_2} = P^{V_1}_{V_2}[T]_{V_1}S^{U_1}_{U_2}[x]_{U_1}\tag{3}$$

Whose matrix representation $[T]^{U_2}_{V_2}\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ then transforms as

$$[T]^{U_2}_{V_2} = P^{V_1}_{V_2}[T]_{V_1}S^{U_1}_{U_2} = (P^{V_2}_{V_1})^{-1}[T]_{V_1}S^{U_1}_{U_2}\tag{4}$$

Does this correctly capture how a matrix transforms under a change of basis?

Comment: It seems you forgot to write down matrix $S$ and its meaning.

Comment: @CunyiNan Thanks, edited.